# React Native expo build failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, package.json, eas

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/POoIL.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzvZE.png)

HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM?

When I running eas build -p android --profile production the build always failed. I already repeated this command and I get the same error. what are the steps to solve this problem in order for me to download already the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-svg-charts` is not updated since Jul 6, 2019 and it is using `react-native-svg@6.2.1` which is not the same version that you are using

I recommend switching to:

- `react-native-chart-kit`
- `react-native-charts-wrapper` (native dependancy
  which require client development build)

Comment: or it is possible to install the latest version of react-native-svg-charts?

Comment: well the latest was 4 years ago.... which is v5